# If $\forall x \in V \space\space\space||T(x)||' \le M||x||$, Then $||T||_{op} \le M$

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Assume that $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V'$ (which are two vector spaces having the inner products $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ and $\left\|\cdot\right\|'$ respectively).
Then, **The operational norm of $T$** is called $\|T\|_{op}$ and defined like this:

$$\|T\|_{op} := \sup\left\lbrace\|T(x)\|':\|x\| \le 1\right\rbrace.$$

---

Assume that $(V,||.||) \to (V',||.||')$ is a linear transformation and we have:

$\exists M \gt 0 \space\space \forall x \in V \space\space\space||T(x)||' \le M||x||$

Prove that $||T||_{op} \le M$.

Any help? I don't see a relevance between the assumption and the statement written above.

Comment: A direct application of the definition of the operational norm should do.

Comment: @user3313320 How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$||T||_{op}$
$=\sup\{||T(x)||':||x||\leq1\}$
$\leq\sup\{M||x||:||x||\leq1\}$
$\leq\sup\{M:||x||\leq1\}$
$=M$